# ReactiveRedisTemplate opsForHash put doesn't overwrite the value

Tags: java, redis, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-data-redis

ReactiveRedisTemplate opsForHash put doesn't overwrite the value.

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().put("NAMESPACE", id, personInfo.toByteArray()).
                    map(resBoolean -> {                     
                        return resBoolean;
                    }).onErrorResume(e -> {
                        return Mono.just(false);
                    });
```

Only when I first call the above method with a new key, the value is stored in Redis. When I call the same method second time with the same value or different value, I get false back.

Does redis put doesn't overwrite the value for the same key ? Is it because, each value stored for the key is immutable ?

If I remove the cache value, I was able to set the value again which is obvious. Pleas help answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the documentation of ReactiveRedisTemplate does not describe what the returned `Boolean` field means.

We can rely on the [official Redis documentation](https://redis.io/commands/hset):

> Return value Integer reply:
>
> The number of fields that were added.

Most probably the ReactiveRedisTemplate translates positive Integer to true and 0 to false. So the returned false value just means that the field is not newly added just overwritten, so your code probably works fine.

Try this example on [try.redis.io](https://try.redis.io/) to see this in action:

```
> HSET myhash field1 "Hello"
(integer) 1
> HSET myhash field1 "Hello2"
(integer) 0
> HGET myhash field1
"Hello2"
```

Comment: The problem is, the new value for the same key is not getting overwritten. As a workaround, I am removing the key value from redis and re-adding it with the new value for the same key.

Comment: Where do you see it is not overwritten? Do you directly look into Redis?

Comment: I do a ```redisTemplate.opsForHash().get("NAMESPACE", deviceId);```